# Mutate a new field showing whether or not the row has any NA values using native pipe placeholder

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to mutate a new field with a bool value if the row contains NA or not.

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  x = 1:5,
  y = 5:1
)

mydf[4,2] <- NA
mydf[3,1] <- NA
```

I now have a data frame that looks like this:

```
mydf
   x  y
1  1  5
2  2  4
3 NA  3
4  4 NA
5  5  1
```

I tried adding a new column to indicate if the row contains NA values:

```
mydf |> mutate(has_na = complete.cases(_))
Error in mutate(mydf, has_na = complete.cases("_")) : 
  invalid use of pipe placeholder
```

How can I add a new column within a pipe chain that indicates whether or not the row contains an NA value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `across` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)

mydf |> 
  mutate(has_na = complete.cases(across()))
#>    x  y has_na
#> 1  1  5   TRUE
#> 2  2  4   TRUE
#> 3 NA  3  FALSE
#> 4  4 NA  FALSE
#> 5  5  1   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the native pipe, you could also define your own "place-holder":

```r
library(tidyverse)

mydf |>
  (\(d) mutate(d, has_na = complete.cases(d)))()
#>    x  y has_na
#> 1  1  5   TRUE
#> 2  2  4   TRUE
#> 3 NA  3  FALSE
#> 4  4 NA  FALSE
#> 5  5  1   TRUE
```